# vs-kubernetes settings empty and I can't see anything in the kubernetes plugin MAC

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, azure-aks

My current kubernetes plugin was working and showed all my clusters but recently they all disappeared. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin, reseting my pc, logging in to azure again, and much more. Recently I tried viewing the settings and I noticed that everything seems to be empty. I tried setting paths and saving but that did not work either (/Users/name/.kube/config). Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to make my plugin work again? It would be greatly appreciated...

```
{
"vs-kubernetes": {

    "vs-kubernetes.namespace": "",
    "vs-kubernetes.kubectl-path": "",
    "vs-kubernetes.helm-path": "",
    "vs-kubernetes.minikube-path": "",
    "vs-kubernetes.kubectlVersioning": "user-provided",
    "vs-kubernetes.outputFormat": "yaml",
    "vs-kubernetes.kubeconfig": "",
    "vs-kubernetes.knownKubeconfigs": [],
    "vs-kubernetes.autoCleanupOnDebugTerminate": false,
    "vs-kubernetes.nodejs-autodetect-remote-root": true,
    "vs-kubernetes.nodejs-remote-root": "",
    "vs-kubernetes.nodejs-debug-port": 9229,
    "checkForMinikubeUpgrade": true,
    "logsDisplay": "webview",
    "imageBuildTool": "Docker"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what version of VS Code you are using? I had a similar problem and updating to 1.54.3 of VS code fixed my issue.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Comment: I'm on 1.57 and still having this issue